# Calling a Python script from C# - changing the script's filepath causes the program to not work

Tags: c#, python

The following code works perfectly without flaw:

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        string pyInterp = File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\config\pathToPythonInterpreter.txt");
        string pyWeather = @"C:\getWeather.py";
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UpdateWeather();
        }

        public void UpdateWeather()
        {
            labelWeather.Text = PySharp.ExecutePy(pyInterp, pyWeather);
        }
    }
```

However, when I change the path to getWeather.py to not be in an arbitrary random location, like this:

```
string pyWeather = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\scripts\getWeather.py";
```

Then my program no longer obtains the script's output. The script still works: I launched it using IDLE and it completed its function properly. When I call it using C#, the console opens, yet no output is obtained.

The Python script is the following:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

r = get("http://www.ilmateenistus.ee/ilm/prognoosid/4-oopaeva-prognoos/")
parsed = soup(r.content, "html.parser")
container = parsed.find("div",{"class":"point kuusiku"})
print(str(container["data-title"]))
```

(It webscrapes my local weather)

[PySharp.ExecutePy() can be viewed here](https://github.com/Mothrakk/ScriptsAndResources/blob/master/Py-Sharp/PySharp/PySharp.cs)

By far the strangest bug I've ever encountered. Any ideas?

EDIT 1: It seems that C# is indeed reading *something* from the script. It just appears that this *something* is.. nothing. I gave the label a default sample text, and after running the program, the label's text is simply changed to an empty string. Hope this incredible discovery helps somehow.

EDIT 2: **The program fails to call the script correctly when its filepath contains spaces**. For example:

```
C:\foo bar\testing\pyWeather.py
```

does not work!

Comment: I tried this out and my first assumption is that your script is causing some error. The output of which gets written to standard error instead of stdout. Try doing merely `print("hello world")` within your python script to see if it shows up on your form. Later, add a `try`/`catch` to see what error it is.

Comment: What is the value returned by `GetCurrentDirectory`? Does it have "\scripts\getWeather.py" underneath? If you are running under `debug` look for `debug\bin` directory or `release\bin` if running under release build. Place the "scripts\getWeather.py" under it. As an aside, that path is not random location.

Comment: Hey shahkalpesh, I tried implementing error handlers both inside the script and inside of the C# project. Unfortunately, nothing was caught. I used `Messagebox.Show()` to see if the filepath was correct and, indeed, it was. I will now try JAugust's proposed solution.

Comment: What is the value of `pyWeather` after `string pyWeather = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\scripts\getWeather.py";`? Does the script file exist on that path? I dont think so.

Comment: The value is `C:\Users\[myname]\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testing\testing\scripts\getWeather.py`. The reason for this is because I changed the directory where the compiled executable gets placed into. The script is there, the filepath is correct. However, I changed `pyWeather` to not use any methods. I changed it into `string pyWeather = @"C:\Users\[myname]\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testing\testing\scripts\getWeather.py";`, similarly to how I did it in the first codeblock in my question, and yet it still doesn't work. Very strange.

Comment: I've made a discovery, refer to my new edit. Any clues on how to fix / get around this?

Comment: Try surrounding the path that contains spaces with 2 double quotes. For e.g.`string pyWeather = @"""C:\Users\[myname]\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testing\testing\scripts\getWeather.py""";` Similarly, you can do `string pyWeather = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\scripts\getWeather.py";` followed by `pyWeather = "\"" + pyWeather  + "\"";`.

Comment: It worked! Feel free to make a solution answer so I can mark you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding the path that contains spaces with 2 double quotes.

For e.g.

`string pyWeather = @"""C:\Users\[myname]\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testing\testing\scripts\getWeather.py""";`

Similarly, you can do `string pyWeather = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\scripts\getWeather.py";` followed by `pyWeather = "\"" + pyWeather + "\"";`.

Answer (score 0):

I would want you to return the answer instead of printing. Printer is an I/O based solution to display. So it will work super fine with IDLE however it may not return results as you expected. I strongly believe this will solve your problem.
instead of printing please try return. I can give more support after trying this.

```
return(str(container["data-title"]))
```

Comment: Hey, I tried what you proposed, but still nothing. I'd like to mention that the first code block in my question still works just as it should; it's the changing of the filepath that suddenly breaks it, so printing the value shouldn't be the cause.